# Why is result of creating a new int array equals to 5?

Tags: java, arrays

This

`new int[][] { { 1, 2, 7 }, { 3, 4, 5 } }[1][2];`

gives a plain int equals to 5 as a result.

I see that this array initialized with some unknown to me method. So, I guess if you will explain what it means and its purpose, everything will become clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new int[][] { { 1, 2, 7 }, { 3, 4, 5 } }` creates an array. `[1]` access the second row `{3, 4, 5}` and then `[2]` gives you five. It's equivalent to something like

```
int[][] t = { { 1, 2, 7 }, { 3, 4, 5 } };
int x = t[1][2];
```

(without `t`).

Answer (score 2):

`new int[][] { { 1, 2, 7 }, { 3, 4, 5 } }` is an array literal. Just as `1` means "integer 1" and `"foo"` means "String `"foo"`", `new int[][] { { 1, 2, 7 }, { 3, 4, 5 } }` means "array of arrays of integers `{ { 1, 2, 7 }, { 3, 4, 5 } }`".

When you have an array, you can index it. Let's call our anonymous array of arrays of integers `harvey`:

```
int[][] harvey = new int[][] { { 1, 2, 7 }, { 3, 4, 5 } }
```

Now `harvey[1]` is "array of integers `{ 3, 4, 5}`", and if we index that again, `harvey[1][2]` is the third value of that array, `5`.

But wherever you could use `harvey`, you could just substitute its value; that is the expression you have.